# Systemd cannot exec a start command with error: No such file or directory, but the path is correct and permissions are correct aswell

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services, java, systemd-unit

So I have this modded minecraft server which has a launch script that is very simple and I wanted to control the server using systemd.
Here is the launch script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Server Launch Script
#
# Thrown together by Neeve in under five minutes, Public Domain
# https://github.com/Neeve01
#
# Fixed and added java version check by t0suj4, Public Domain
# https://github.com/t0suj4

# DO NOT EDIT UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING
FORGEJAR='forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar'
JAVA_PARAMETERS=''

# these you can edit
MIN_RAM='2048M'
MAX_RAM='12000M'

# DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING PAST THIS LINE
LAUNCHPARAMS="-server -Xms$MIN_RAM -Xmx$MAX_RAM $JAVA_PARAMETERS -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2_112-116.xml -jar $FORGEJAR nogui"

echo "Checking java version..."
echo
java -version
echo
echo "The expected java version is 1.8. Not higher, not lower."
echo

echo "Launching the server..."
echo
echo "> java $LAUNCHPARAMS"

java $LAUNCHPARAMS

echo
echo "- The server has stopped. If it's a crash, please read the output above."
echo
read -p "- Press Return to exit..." _
```

And here is an *ls -la* of the wokring directory:

```
drwxrwxrwx 15 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Dec 24 13:14 .
drwxrwxr-x  7 mux         mux             4096 Dec 24 01:18 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory        2 Dec 24 01:25 banned-ips.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory        2 Dec 24 01:25 banned-players.json
drwxrwxrwx  3 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Nov  9 22:43 bansoukou
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory     1053 Nov  9 22:43 CHANGELOG.md
drwxrwxrwx 32 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Dec 24 01:19 config
drwxrwxrwx  4 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Nov  9 22:43 config-overrides
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory     9375 Dec 24 12:38 crafttweaker.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory      180 Dec 24 01:20 eula.txt
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory  4466148 Nov  9 22:42 forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar
drwxrwxrwx  3 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Dec 24 01:25 journeymap
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory      916 Nov  9 22:43 launch.bat
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory      897 Dec 24 01:30 launch.sh
drwxrwxrwx  7 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Nov  9 22:42 libraries
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory     7817 Nov  9 22:43 LICENSE.md
drwxrwxrwx  4 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Dec 24 01:20 local
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory     1159 Nov  9 22:43 log4j2_112-116.xml
drwxrwxrwx  2 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Dec 24 02:38 logs
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory 30222121 Feb 11  2022 minecraft_server.1.12.2.jar
drwxrwxrwx  3 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Dec 24 01:19 .mixin.out
drwxrwxrwx  4 nomifactory nomifactory    12288 Dec 24 01:19 mods
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory        2 Dec 24 01:25 ops.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory       15 Dec 24 01:20 options.txt
drwxrwxrwx  2 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Dec 24 01:20 patchouli_books
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory      702 Nov  9 22:42 README.md
drwxrwxrwx  3 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Nov  9 22:43 scripts
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory      752 Dec 24 01:25 server.properties
drwxrwxrwx  2 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Dec 24 01:21 TombManyGraves
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory        2 Dec 24 01:25 usercache.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 nomifactory nomifactory        2 Dec 24 01:25 whitelist.json
drwxrwxrwx 13 nomifactory nomifactory     4096 Dec 24 01:27 world
```

I wrote the following Unit file for it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nomifactory Server
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
User=nomifactory
Group=nomifactory
Nice=1
KillSignal=SIGTERM
WorkingDirectory=/home/mux/mcs/nomifactory
ExecStart="/usr/bin/java -server -Xms2048M -Xmx12000M -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2_112-116.xml -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui"
#ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/nomifactory
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I try to start the service it fails with this error (excerpt from journalctl):

```
Dec 24 12:56:02 johann-serve systemd[1]: Started Nomifactory Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit nomifactory.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit nomifactory.service has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 232408.
Dec 24 12:56:02 johann-serve systemd[2579244]: nomifactory.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Dec 24 12:56:02 johann-serve systemd[2579244]: nomifactory.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/java -server -Xms2048M -Xmx12000M -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2_112-116.xml -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui: No such file or directory
-- Subject: Process /usr/bin/java -server -Xms2048M -Xmx12000M -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2_112-116.xml -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The process /usr/bin/java -server -Xms2048M -Xmx12000M -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2_112-116.xml -jar forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar nogui could not be executed and failed.
--
-- The error number returned by this process is ERRNO.
Dec 24 12:56:02 johann-serve systemd[1]: nomifactory.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit nomifactory.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 203.
Dec 24 12:56:02 johann-serve systemd[1]: nomifactory.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit nomifactory.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
```

A few FAQ-Answers to round it all up:

- I tried to *su* into the nomifactory user to execute the command specified in *ExecStart* in the same directory as specified in *WorkingDirectory* and it starts normally. The error only comes up when started with systemd.
- All necessary files and directories (apart from the java executable) are inside the working directory.
- owner and group of the working directory are *nomifactory* (they have 777 permission now anyway xd).
- All directories in the path are readable and executable for *nomifactory*

I hope someone can help me achieve this seemingly trivial task and I'm probably an idiot but I just don't see it.

Comment: That `Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/java -server ... nogui: No such file or directory` looks a lot like it trying to take the full string as the program file name. I can't remember the quoting rules for systemd (or where to find them in the docs), but the files on my system have lines like `ExecStart=/usr/bin/find /var/lib/sudo -exec /usr/bin/touch -d @0 '{}' \073`, so I'd try without the quotes on the ExecStart line. (Though in the post here, the line only seems to have a quote at the start, but I'm not sure if that's a typo)

Comment: see ["Command lines" in the systemd.service manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines)

Comment: I missed the closing double quote when copying, it is there in the file. But now trying without the double quotes it works. I suspected that it was something dumb, but you probably saved me a lot of time and grief. ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @ilkkachu solved the issue for me, if anyone has a similar problem check for double quotes in your `ExecStart` directives!